# How to exclude an endpoint from CSRF middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

*See update below...*

My React front-end is able to call upon my Node back-end API. However, when an external site calls upon my API, it receives an error. If I comment out the CSRF part (the 5 lines) of the setup, then 3rd party services ARE able to call upon my API.

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const csurf = require("csurf");
var cors = require("cors");

var corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN_URL.split(","),
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(
    cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, {
        sameSite: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        maxAge: process.env.COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
    })
);

// If I comment out the next 5 lines, 3rd party services CAN call upon my API
app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
    next();
});

app.use("/api/csrf", (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json({
        status: true,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
    });
});

app.use("/api", api);
```

---

**Update**

I would like to wrap the CSRF configuration in an if-else statement, depending on the requested route (see below). This seems to work, but **is this a correct and secure setup?**

```
var csrf = csurf({ cookie: true });

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // skip csrf for certain routes
    if (req.url === '/api/mollie_webhook') {
        return next();
    } else {
        app.use(csrf);
        // Is this allowed? Since we already have app.use 4 lines up, but don't know how else to do this...

        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
            next();
        });

        app.use("/api/csrf", (req, res) => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
                csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
            });
        });

        next();
    }
});

app.use("/api", api);
```

Comment: It's not a CORS error, simply because the SOP isn't enforced by user agents other than browsers.

Comment: I don't know, but this question isn't related to CORS.

Comment: What do you mean you get a 301 error in return? Return from what? They are posting to you...

Comment: Ah, I mean my server gives them a 301 error back when they try to post.

Comment: Have you tried adding `app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))`

Comment: Yes it's there, it's the first line of those 5 lines I need to comment out to enable an external service to call upon the API.

Comment: Do you have a `error handler` if so what error are you receiving exactly?

Comment: When I test it in Postman I get the error: "invalid csrf token". I don't send along a csrf token in the header, since I assume that the payment gateway that will speak to my API endpoint will also not send along a CSRF token... I know only the basics of CSRF. Does this situation suggest that one should "turn off" CSRF for API endpoints that are supposed to be accessible by external services? Such as a payment gateway sending an update about a payment to my webhook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to declare the Web Hook route before you add the CSRF middleware.

However, you can apply the CSRF protection conditionally by skipping directly to the `next` middleware on specific ignored routes.

You will also need to enable CORS on the webhook route to allow incoming requests from the remote server.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const csurf = require('csurf');
const cookies = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();

const shared = cors({
  origin: 'https://api.mollie.com',
  methods: 'POST'
});

const protect = csurf({ cookie: true });
const ignore = [ '/api/webhook' ];

app.use(cookies(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, {
  sameSite: true, httpOnly: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  maxAge: process.env.COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (ignore.includes(req.url)) {
    next();
  } else {
    protect(req, res, next);
  }
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.csrfToken) {
    res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
  } next();
});

app.use('/api/webhook', shared, (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.use("/api/csrf", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    status: true,
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Thanks, because I define my routes in a separate file and would like to keep it that way, I prefer to wrap the csrf-logic in an if-else statement, like I try to do in the update of my post. Is that also possible and if so, what would that look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer to behave the way you described.

Comment: Thanks! I think, if you place the `app.use("/api/csrf",` block inside the `else` statement: then I think you no longer need the `app.use('/api/webhook'` block. Would you say that that would be okay as well?

Comment: **DO NOT** call the `use` method inside a route handler. Doing so will stack an extra handler onto your app every time that route it is accessed and eventually your process will run out of memory.

Express middleware is meant to be chained. The code I posted is the proper way to accomplish what you want. If the route is in the ignored list call the next middleware, otherwise apply the CSRF protection which then calls the next middleware.

Also, you **MUST** explicitly declare the webhook route as I have done because it requires that the CORS middleware be applied to it.

Comment: Actually, you *may not* **need** the CORS middleware. Generally only browser user agents respect the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as a security measure to protect users from XSS attacks. When the Mollie API sends the POST request to your Web Hook URL it may completely disregard this header. Applying it certainly won't hurt though and *could* prevent external parties from tampering with your API.

Comment: I've removed two blocks from your solution: 1) code block `const shared = cors ...` and 2) code block `app.use('/api/webhook'`. It seems to work and those code blocks don't seem to be needed. But my original code also has a code block: `app.use(function (req, res, next) {``res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());``});` that you didn't use. I think it sets a cookie and I assume my repository needs that... But if I include that code block in your solution just before `app.use("/api/csrf"...`, it produces the error `req.csrfToken() is not a function`. Shouldn't that code block be added somehow?

Comment: Configuring csurf wth the `cookie:true` option automatically sets a cookie named `_csrf`. If you definitely need it to be named `XSRF-TOKEN`, just set that conditionally in another middleware as I've done in my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks, last question :) It seems to work with and without the code block: `app.use('/api/webhook'...`. (without `shared` in it). Is it really needed?

Comment: Technically you don't **NEED** to use a webhook at all. This is optional in the Mollie API. However, if you want to be informed of payment status updates you will need to handle those incoming requests, this can be done in your other file where your other API routes are declared. You likely don't need CORS enabled on this route though.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the purpose of CSRF protection. CSRF protection is to prevent direct posting of data to your site. In other words, the client must actually post through an approved path like filling data to a form and submit it.

So an api will precludes Csrf, because its purpose is generally to allow 3rd party entities to access and modify data on your site . So as a rule any API view should not be use CSRF. And you can protect your endpoint in various ways such as oauth and there are other best practices too

Comment: In general this is not true. An api must also be protected against CSRF if authentication is based on something sent by the browser automatically (like for example a token in a cookie). Also oauth is totally unrelated and btw overused by many.

Comment: Agreed if the API is not for the same domain.